# Python mechanize hangs on br.open(url) with self._sleep(pause) traceback

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I have written a python function to rate websites according to some parameters (a series of words). The function uses Python Mechanize and it works fine most of the time.

However, for some websites it just hangs there until I ctrl+c on the terminal. I'm guessing this is some sort of javascript related problem, is there a way to build a time-out function around this?

This is my function:

```
def rateSite(site_url,comparisonWords):
   #open the site
   localBrowser = mechanize.Browser()
   localBrowser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.1 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/9.0.1')]
   localBrowser.set_handle_robots(False)
   site = localBrowser.open(site_url,timeout=5000)
   html = site.read()

   #rate the site
   for i in comparisonWords.split():
      #do some rating math

   return rating
```

and this is the traceback I get on ctrl+c:

```
site=localBrowser.open(site_url,timeout=5000)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 209, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 236, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 202, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_http.py", line 612, in http_response
    "http", request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 219, in error
    result = apply(self._call_chain, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_http.py", line 146, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 209, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 236, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 202, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_http.py", line 612, in http_response
    "http", request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 219, in error
    result = apply(self._call_chain, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_http.py", line 146, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 209, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 236, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 202, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_http.py", line 612, in http_response
    "http", request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 219, in error
    result = apply(self._call_chain, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_http.py", line 146, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 209, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 236, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 202, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_http.py", line 578, in http_response
    self._sleep(pause)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any help on how to solve this or build a time-out for it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeout=5000` is more than one hour; you might mean `timeout=5`.

By default `mechanize` follows at most 10 redirects before giving up, see `HTTPRedirectHandler.max_redirections`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work fine. I thought the timeout value was in milliseconds.